# How to make a photosphere/360 panorama type camera in iOS

Tags: ios, image-stitching, 360-degrees, photosphere

I need to be able to create a camera experience something like photosphere or 360 panorama app. Where you take a photo then rotate your body around to be able to take your next photo until you reach the full way around, while this is happening these photos are being stitched to each other together under the hood.

So if somebody can give me a an overview how this can be done would be great. Any libraries I should be using or APIs that can start me off and a brief step by step.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I never did. It's very very complex